# Issue with node.js and mongoskin error handling

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning and trying simple example using node.js and mongoskin. here is my function below

Problem following function is, if the mongodb server is disconnected then also I get the "err=null" hence not able catch connection error. If I restart node.js server (while mongoDB server is still disconnected) I get error as 
"[Error: failed to connect to [server-aa070:27017]]"

```
// Process messages from client
   app.post('/send', function(req, res){
   var message = {
        id: i++,
      nickname: req.param('nickname', 'Anonymous'),
          text: req.param('text', ''),
created_at: new Date()
};

conn.chat_log.insert(message, function(err) {
   if(err!==null){
   console.log(err);
   }
   else {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(err);
   }
});
res.json({status: 'ok'});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure mongo is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to node.js and mongodb, but why are you using `if(err!==null)` rather than `if(err)`? If I'm understanding correctly, wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, I think I did misunderstand your problem. Sorry. Are you saying that when you can't connect to the DB, you're not getting an error that has the value "null"?

Comment: I mean I need some way to understand that mongoDB is not connected, whenever it get's disconnected in node.js. so That err object should return error something like "MongoDB is not connected"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about mongoskin, but for the node-mongo-native driver (the driver that mongoskin is built on), the author said:

> Note that there's no reason to pass a callback to the insert or update
>   commands unless you use the safe:true option. If you don't specify
>   safe:true, then your callback will be called immediately.